# What is the process for using MySQL from Python in Windows?

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-connection

I come from a PHP background where MySQL easily works from PHP, and don't the process for getting MySQL to work from Python.  From all the research i did and reading of similar yet non-exact questions, it seems *to me* that there are different ways to achieve this, which makes it even harder for me to wrap my head around.  So far I have MySQL-python-1.2.3 installed for python 2.7.1 in Windows XP 32Bit.  Can anyone give me an overview of what is necessary to get MySQL working from Python in Windows, or even what is next after my steps all the way to fetching a table row?  *Thanks in advance*.

#### UPDATE:

@Mahmoud, using your suggestion i have triggered the following:
[image]

Comment: The last line of the update says access denied for user.  Are you using the correct username/password?

Comment: Why don't you have a password, btw? It says "using password: NO".

Comment: @vpit3833,@9000 - Looking at the parameters Mahmoud suggest to pass the connect method, there is no username parameter, i don't know why.  I haven't set up a password for MySQL yet so i use username root and password '' and that works fine from MySQL and phpMyAdmin.

Comment: OK, a more elaborate signature looks like `MySQLdb.connect(host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database_name)`.  Password being empty is OK as long as you are just learning and mucking around :)

Comment: @vpit3833, I'll update my answer

Comment: @Babiker: did this get solved? Maybe you want to accept the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use the DBAPI, then here's a simple snippet explaining how to issue a SELECT query.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", user="username", passwd="your-pass", db="the-db-name")
```

To perform a query, you first need a cursor, and then you can execute queries on it:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
max_age = 42
cursor.execute("""SELECT name FROM employees WHERE age < %s""", (max_age,))
print cursor.fetchone()
```

**However**, you most likely want to use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), I recommend [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). It essentially trivializes database interaction by providing a super-powerful abstraction layer.